# How can I restore the partition table of a USB drive?

Tags: windows, partitioning, data-recovery

I accidentally used diskparts "clean"-command on a wrong drive. I deleted its exFat partition table. How can I restore it on Windows (without using some expensive and clunky third recovery shareware)
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: How many partitions did the disk have?

Comment: partition recovery usually indicates Testdisk. I don't believe windows has any built in partition recovery utilities. be sure to recover to another disk, to be safe. https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download

Comment: **Free** third-party tools such as DiskGenius makes this easy -- remove all partitions (i.e., convert all to free space) and then create one or more exFAT (or perhaps FAT32) partitions. You might be able to do this with Windows Disk Management, too, though I find DiskGenius easier to use.